# drop rows if before match code within an order

Tags: r

I have a series of individuals represented by ID's that are associated with addresses in an order. Some, but not all, of those individuals have an address with a positive match code (matchcode = 1). I want to drop all the addresses before that match code, keeping the one with the positive match code, and the ones after. I also want to keep all the addresses if the person does not have a positive match code. So, from this dummy data:

```
ID = c("id1", "id1", "id1", "id2", "id2", "id2", "id3", "id3", "id3", "id4", "id4", "id4")
matchcode = c(0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0)
address = c("a", "b", "c", "d", "e", "f", "g", "h", "i", "j", "k", "l")

df = data.frame(ID, matchcode, address)

df <- df %>% group_by(ID) %>% mutate(order = row_number()) %>% ungroup
```

I would like to get this:

```
  ID    matchcode address order
  <chr>     <dbl> <chr>   <int>
1 id1           0 a           1
2 id1           1 b           2
3 id2           0 d           1
4 id2           0 e           2
5 id2           1 f           3
6 id3           0 g           1
7 id3           0 h           2
8 id3           0 i           3
9 id4           1 j           1
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After grouping by 'ID', `match` the position of 1 in the 'matchcode', get the `seq`uence and use `slice` to subset the rows. If there are not cases, `nomatch` will return the number of rows (`n()`), thus we get all the observations

```
library(dplyr)
df %>% 
  group_by(ID) %>%
  slice(seq_len(match(1, matchcode, nomatch = n()))) %>%
  ungroup
```

-output

```
# A tibble: 9 × 4
  ID    matchcode address order
  <chr>     <dbl> <chr>   <int>
1 id1           0 a           1
2 id1           1 b           2
3 id2           0 d           1
4 id2           0 e           2
5 id2           1 f           3
6 id3           0 g           1
7 id3           0 h           2
8 id3           0 i           3
9 id4           1 j           1
```

---

Or with `filter`

```
df %>%
   group_by(ID) %>% 
   filter(cumsum(c(0, diff(matchcode))) >=0) %>%
   ungroup
```

-output

```
# A tibble: 10 × 4
   ID    matchcode address order
   <chr>     <dbl> <chr>   <int>
 1 id1           0 a           1
 2 id1           1 b           2
 3 id1           0 c           3
 4 id2           0 d           1
 5 id2           0 e           2
 6 id2           1 f           3
 7 id3           0 g           1
 8 id3           0 h           2
 9 id3           0 i           3
10 id4           1 j           1
```